# How to escape special character in solr fl query

Tags: solr

I have a document ingested in Solr having a field ***Can Ship Int'l***
I want to filter the Solr query response and fetch on field ***Can Ship Int'l*** . 
when I pass fl=custom_string_Can Ship Int'l as a query paramtere I am getting

> 

```
{   "requestId": null,   "service": "prod-search-service",   "errors":
> [
>     {
>       "message": "The query contains an undefined field.",
>       "code": 1026,
>       "description": "The search service could not process the query, because it contains a field name that is not defined for the search
> collection. To solve the issue, make sure the query contains only
> names of fields that are defined in the search collection schema.
> Refer to the service API specification for information on available
> fields.",
>       "level": "ERROR",
>       "locale": ""
>     }   ] }
```

How should I form a query that I get the desired output?

Comment: can you share the fields defined in the schema...?

Comment: I don't have the schema with me, its at client's side.
I tired with fl=custom_string_Can?Ship?Int?l and its working but not sure how correct it is .

Comment: Use `\\` to escape special characters - be aware that you might have to escape it twice, since the string may need escaping in your application as well.